# How do I generate Entity Framework 4.0 classes from the command line that have different names than my schema objects?

Tags: entity-framework, command-line

I want to generate Entity Framework 4.0 classes from a (legacy) database from a command line, but I have 2 transformations I want:

1. Tables/columns are lowerCamelCase and I want my classes/members to be UpperCamelCase.
2. I want to suffix my classes with "Dto".

Any idea how this might be accomplished?  I'm a total newbie to EF, but I have a decent understanding of Linq to Sql and was able to accomplish the same task by doing:  sqlmetal -> dbml -> xml mapping file and .cs file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The EDMX is also XML. If you're comfortable with XML transformations, just change the CSDL section of the file per your renaming rules. Then do a full build on your app and the code should be regenerated. To do this from the command line, use `EdmGen`, which comes with the framework. The free [EdmGen2](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EdmGen2) utility is worth a look; it may already do some of what you need.